# Когда я нажимаю на кнопку в попытке открыть следующее activity приложение вылетает

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Когда я нажимаю на кнопку в попытке открыть следующее activity приложение вылетает (хочу открыть fctivity registration)
вот код:

```
package com.greenprojectinfo.ideabank

import android.content.Intent
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val btnTA = findViewById(R.id.btnTA)
        btnTA.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, Donation::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        val btnDon = findViewById(R.id.btnDon)
        btnDon.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, TakingAway::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        val btnMEN = findViewById(R.id.btnMEN)
        btnMEN.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, Mentor::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)

        }

        val btnMon = findViewById(R.id.btnMon)
        btnMon.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, Fond::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)

        }
        val btnSql = findViewById(R.id.btnSql)
        btnSql.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, Registration::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)

        }

    }
```

вот код xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="@drawable/kek"
>

    <Button
            android:text="ИДЕИ ДЛЯ ПРОЕКТА"
            android:layout_width="220dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/btnTA"
            android:background="@drawable/zubenko"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="61dp" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="95dp" android:layout_marginStart="95dp" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="96dp" android:layout_marginRight="96dp" android:layout_marginBottom="133dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnMEN"/>
    <Button
            android:text="ПРЕДЛОЖИТЬ ИДЕЮ"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_width="220dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/btnDon"
            android:background="@drawable/zubenko"

            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnMEN" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="104dp" android:layout_marginStart="104dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="104dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="104dp"/>
    <Button
            android:text="МЕНТОРЫ"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_width="220dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/btnMEN"
            android:background="@drawable/zubenko"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnTA" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="104dp" android:layout_marginStart="104dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="104dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="104dp"/>
    <Button
            android:text="ФОНДЫ"
            android:background="@drawable/zubenko"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:layout_width="220dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/btnMon"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnDon"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginLeft="104dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="104dp" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="104dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="104dp"/>
    <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnSql" android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnMon" app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="34dp" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="161dp" android:layout_marginStart="161dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="162dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="162dp"


    />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Логи то покажите =/

Answer (score 6):

у вас `this` чужой, от лямбды, он не унаследован от `Context`

```
val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, Donation::class.java)
startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: да, эта порочная this практика

Comment: извините , а как это поправить ?

Comment: так ответ с исправлением